# Javascript: Get dimensions and size of an image in one request

Tags: javascript

Based on other posts here, I have written this to get the dimensions and size of a file

```
    const newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = () => {
      console.log('height ' + newImg.height);
      console.log('width ' + newImg.width);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.google.com/myImage.png', true);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
          console.log('size ' + this.response.byteLength);
        }
      };
      xhr.send(null);
   }

   newImg.src = 'https://www.google.com/myImage.png';
```

While it works, I was wondering if I could combine both in one, meaning doing **only** either the `Image onLoad` or the `xhr` request ?

Comment: Make only the XHR request, and then create an image element from the recieved data afterwards, by transforming the actual response body content into a Data URI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid a second network roundtrip by using a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```
fetch('https://cdn.glitch.com/2eddb7d4-12e2-45ae-8d27-738f13fb514a%2FGOPR1017_1586689900523.JPG?v=1587457335788')
.then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => {
  console.log('Size: ' + buffer.byteLength)
  const blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: 'image/jpeg'})
  const img = new Image()
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log(img.width, img.height)    
  }
})
```

Note that you still need the `onload` callback as the browser takes a bit of time to parse the image, but in this case it won't cause a network roundtrip.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question, but I can give you another useful info:

Image is a weird animal, it behaves differently depending on the browser, the context and the pixel density. To be sure to catch the natural dimensions of your image, use:

```
newImg.naturalHeight;
newImg.naturalWidth;
```

instead of `newImg.width` or `newImg.clientWidth`.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight

Have fun!